# GOA: Google account unreachable using wired connection

Tags: networking, internet, online-accounts

Besides taking a few minutes, I can successfully add a Google account through [GOA](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/goa-daemon.8.html) using a wired network, but accessing it (through Nautilus or Geary for example) returns timeout errors.

Problem appears to be network related cause when I switch to Wifi, it works fine adding and accessing.

I am using Gnome 3.34 on Ubuntu Desktop 19:10. My computer is connected to my ISP router directly (no proxy).

What I tried so far:

- removing Webkit caches in some places like `~/.cache/gnome-control-center/WebKitCache/` or 
  `~/.local/share/webkitgtk`;
- Checking configuration files: `NetworkManager.conf`, `interfaces`, `hosts`, `goa`…
- reinstalling package `network-manager` and its interface for Gnome `network-manager-gnome`;
- reinstalling package `gnome-control-center`;

What would you advice me to do?
Thank you

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem: [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) was not set in netplan configuration file, located in `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`.

Original content was:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I added my interface enp3s0 to be dynamically assigned:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

It is possible to list all interfaces using `ip a` command.

And then applied configuration:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

I found the information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#ip-addressing) in the official Ubuntu documentation.

Hope it could help.